# Which dialect of C is Objective-C a "strict superset" of?

Tags: objective-c, c

I frequently hear that Objective-C is a "strict superset" of the C programming language. There are several dialects/standards of C (ie. K&R, ANSI C, C90, C99, GNU extensions...); Objective-C was first developed in the early 1980s, so it has to predate these standards. However, Objective-C 2.0 is from around 2006 or 2007, so it could be based on a more modern C dialect. So, which "C" is Objective-C a superset of?

Answer (score 7):

There's a corresponding "dialect" of Objective-C for all the standard dialects of C.

Comment: `@Chuck:` ...and some of the *non-standard* dialects of C!

Answer (score 2):

Given that the most commonly used Objective-C compilers (GCC and Clang) are also C compilers, one would imagine that they support the C dialect(s) supported by these compilers.  Apple's documentation specifically states:

> The Apple
>   compilers are based on the compilers
>   of the GNU Compiler Collection.
>   Objective-C syntax is a superset of
>   GNU C/C++ syntax, and the Objective-C
>   compiler works for C, C++ and
>   Objective-C source code. The compiler
>   recognizes Objective-C source files by
>   the filename extension .m, just as it
>   recognizes files containing only
>   standard C syntax by filename
>   extension .c. Similarly, the compiler
>   recognizes C++ files that use
>   Objective-C by the extension .mm.
>   Other issues when using Objective-C
>   with C++ are covered in “Using C++
>   With Objective-C”

So in this case Objective-C is simply regarded as an extension of either the C or C++ compiler depending on which you choose as the base language.

Comment: As of Xcode 4.4, the C dialect seems to be set to "GNU99" by default.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for isn't really defined. Objective C is usually thought of a strict superset of ANSI-C (which is the same as C90). However, Objective C isn't a standardized language or anything of that sort. It's description basically is "Take C, and add these features to it". It's therefore dependent on the particular compiler you're using.

Comment: Now I have to wonder how Xcode deals with C99 strict aliasing rules when compiling Objective-C code...

Comment: @iPhone Developer: I've never used Xcode, but iirc it's based on some form of GCC. If that is the case, then it should support any of the standards of C underlying objective C itself.

Comment: `@Billy ONeal:` Indeed: http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2005/Aug/msg00050.html

Comment: @iPhone Developer: All pointers to object types are equivalent to `id`, but get special type-checking from the Objective-C compiler.

Comment: "ANSI C" is not the same as C90. ANSI C is aligned with ISO C, whose present version is C99+TC1/2/3.

Comment: @R. Most people referring to ANSI C are distinguishing it from K&R C, and are referring to C89 or C90, not C99.

Comment: @iPhone Developer: The "strict aliasing" rules aren't new in C99 - the same rules existed in C90.  The reason it has recently been raised as an issue is that GCC has started taking advantage of them for optimisation.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: those people are using the name inaccurately; "ANSI C" has a clear, well-defined meaning.  The fact that a lot of people are ignorant of that fact does not change the meaning of the term.

Comment: @Stephen: 1. I respectfully disagree. The word "hacker" isn't meant to have a negative connotation either, but it does in reality. Language is what people understand it as, not what happens to be written down on a piece of paper somewhere. 2. Most nobody uses the phrase "ANSI C" anymore in any case. The few places it's common to see it are distinguishing from K&R C, and those places were usually written before C99 was created, meaning that they actually refer to C89/C90, not C99. In either case, it's best to specify C89/90 or C99 explicitly or people **will** get confused like this.

Comment: @Billy ONeal: When discussing common language, I agree with the perspective you take -- words mean what people take them to mean.  But we're not discussing common language; we're discussing language standards, and the terms have precise domain-specific meanings, divorced from "how the word is typically used".  It's not possible to write or discuss a standard without this sort of strict interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

According to "[Learning Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html)" from Apple:

"Objective-C is a superset of the ANSI version of the C programming language and supports the same basic syntax as C."