# If Objective C is a strict superset of C, then why doesn't this compile?

Tags: objective-c

Consider the following source file, which is (at least should be) valid C.

```
void id() {
}
```

I am trying to compile it with `gcc -c test.m`, but I get the following error:

```
test.m:1: error: ‘id’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
<built-in>:0: error: previous declaration of ‘id’ was here
```

If Obj-C were a strict superset, wouldn't it mean that all valid C programs also valid Obj-C programs? Note that I am not `#import`ing anything, nor am I linking.

Granted, maybe LLVM(1) is doing something magical by default, or maybe this is a bug in it.

(1): i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)

**EDIT**: Let me clarify this question - the question is not about the `id` part, I know it has special meaning. My point is that it is commonly said that Obj-C is a strict superset of C. However, this can't be the case if it has **keywords** that conflict with valid C programs.

So either **id** is not reserved by the compiler, or Obj-C is not a strict superset. The point of this question is to ask which is the case, or is there something obvious I am missing.

Comment: id is a defined type in Objecive-C.

Comment: `id` is a reserved word in Objective-C. Have you checked for imports on `Prefix.pch`?

Comment: I don't have a prefix header, just test.m. I know that id has special meaning in Obj-C.

Comment: This is new behavior -- reusing `id`, e.g. `id id = [[Something alloc] init];` used to be legal, as recently as whatever clang version came with Xcode 4.2 (2.something?).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Superset means it adds some extra features too. Like `id` in this case. It is a defined type in Objective C. And these [extra features](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Articles/ocLanguageSummary.html) of the superset always supersede the subset.

**Its just customary that people use the term *strict superset*. You need to take it with a pinch of salt!**

See these old posts in SO for a similar discussion

[Is objective C 2.0 a proper superset of C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963832/is-objective-c-2-0-a-proper-superset-of-c)

[Which dialect of C is Objective-C a "strict superset" of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317652/which-dialect-of-c-is-objective-c-a-strict-superset-of)

Comment: Thank you, I was afraid for a moment that nobody understood my question according to the comments I received :)

Answer (score 0):

`id` is a keyword for "any type of object" in ObjectiveC. In C it'd probably same as writing

```
void int() {
}
```

Comment: So in your opinion, Objective C is not a strict superset of C? After all, it can't be if it introduces conflicting keywords in the common namespace.

Comment: If your main concern is about the definition of "strict" then I don't have any opinion on this matter .) I just remember reading that it's a superset of C.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main concern :) I edited the original question and I hope its purpose is now a bit clearer.